# Не работает вызов функции в python

Tags: python, функции, pycharm, jupyter-notebook

```
def func(arg1, arg2, arg3):

    return arg1 - arg2

func(1, 2, 0)
```

последняя строчка в коде не рабочая, в самом **IDLE** и **Pycharm** ничего не выводится. Зашёл на **Jupyter** и  там все работает. У питона самая последняя версия 3.11.2, в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Почему вы думаете, что она не работает?

Comment: Так вы печатайте результат: `print(func(1, 2, 0))` То, что `Jupyter` самостоятельно печатает последний объект в ячейке - это фича именно юпитера, а не Питона в целом. Ну, вернее не только юпитера, `ipython` вроде так делает, не помню где ещё он кроме юпитера используется.

Comment: функция создаётся, добавляются аргументы, но не вызывается

Comment: ааааа, все так просто, спасибо)